# Where to find all Apple Store editors' stories?

Tags: ios-appstore

I would like to read all stories which were posted in Apple Store on ios. [For example.](https://itunes.apple.com/story/id1273615890?l=en). The app itself only shows Andre, where can I find older ones?

Comment: The stories are in the App Store, what doesn‘t work Formalien with reading the stories there?

Comment: I can see only recent ones. But is it possible to find stories which were posted before?

Comment: Ah, good point!